# Is Rhythmbox able to queue tracks played while it is offline, to scrobble them later?

Tags: rhythmbox

I'm wondering if Rhythmbox is able to queue tracks played while it is offline, to submit them to Last.fm later when an internet connection becomes available.

I think Banshee supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried it just now on Ubuntu 12.04.2 Live USB. I am still searching the cache file that saves the play counts, which is certainly needed for submitting to Last.fm server when the connection becomes available.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me with a Xubuntu 12.04.2 system.